# Import in GCP is broken when using EXTENSION

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

After exporting a database that use a postgis type (row with geometry type) from GCP platform. If I try to import the dump to another instance it throw an exception because of the postgis geometry type.

I can not create the extension before importing the database dump or the dump won't work and say that the schema already exist.

Is the only solution to export all the schemas/tables (and then remove the schema manually inside the file) and then export all the data ? (can not do it directly inside the dump file since it is more than 200Go+.)

PostgreSQL 13.7
Postgis 3.0.2

Comment: This is lacking details. What versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS? Which function? What is the error message? Which schema are you talking about?

Comment: I don't think the version is very relevant in that case, it is more of a process problem. 

PostgreSQL 13.7 
Postgis 3.0.2

Comment: Perhaps it is relevant, perhaps not. Better err on the side of giving more information. What about my other questions?

Comment: Did not :( @melchoir55